# Is the Model in a MVC design just a database?

Tags: model-view-controller

Is the Model portion of the Model-View-Controller design simply just a databse or mostly a database?  A persistant storage area inwhich data is stores sounds like a database to me.

Comment: Yes, but not necessarily - the "model" refers to the representation of your business entities or conceptual objects, which is often, but not always, simply a database (or rather, ORM objects representing data in the database). However, don't confuse a `Model` with a `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 2):

*That depends as there are scenarios with which you want to start your application*. Like for e.g. you have the database initially and then you are designing your model or on the other hand you have the model on the basis of which you design your database. So whatever the case may be the model act as a container to hold the data in the flow of the Application.

So we can go with either of the situations. There are various kinds of approaches to follow.

- Database First approach
- Code First approach.
- Model First

Please read [this link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-models-and-data-access) for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No. As far as I know, models are different from the database because all models need not necessarily be mapped to a database. For example, model objects can be used just to manipulate data into a form which you need for a particular situation like sending a complex data which consists of a combination of entities or their properties but are required on a regular basis in the form of json or xml. In these situations it would be easier to just keep those as models so that they can be processed easily but they do not necessarily persist very long.

Here is a good link which should help you get some further insight:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mvc-for-noobs--net-10488